# understanding pointer to a structure refers to pointer member in c in accessing it

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a below program and compilation is success but while running,program crashes in eclipse

```
struct Student
{
   unsigned int  *ptr;  //Stores address of integer Variable
}*s1;

int main()
{
    unsigned int roll = 20;
    s1->ptr   = &roll;

    printf("\nRoll Number of Student : %d",*(s1->ptr));

    return(0);
}
```

how to print the value of roll using pointer to a structure

Comment: s1 is not allocated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `Student` structure, allocate it and use it

```
typedef struct Student
{
   unsigned int  *ptr;  //Stores address of integer Variable
} Student;

int main()
{
    Student *s1;
    unsigned int roll = 20;
    s1 = malloc(sizeof(Student));
    if (s1 == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    s1->ptr   = &roll;

    printf("\nRoll Number of Student : %d",*(s1->ptr));
    free(s1);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: I just want to declare pointer to a structure and to access *ptr member through it...Here i see that s1 is just a structure and not pointer to a structure. am i right?

Comment: If you want a pointer you have to use `malloc` to allocate it. I will update the code

Comment: Thanks Orel.  For better understanding of this concept,Is it not possible to assign the value of *ptr member without using malloc() ? .... the other way is that can we initialize the structure member with some address of variable as mentioned in question ?

Comment: Your pointer needs to point somewhere, if you are not using the stack you need to use the heap.

Comment: so what i understand is that  *s1 should point to either stack memory or heap memory.  But,in my code, *s1 doesn't point to stack memory and that causes the problem right? so s1->ptr   = &roll; is not valid statement

Comment: Yes in your case s1 is null, the global are set to 0. So s1->ptr is invalid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144414/discussion-between-danny-and-orel).